# Zero of a complex polynomial satisfying one of three assertions.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1$. Prove that if $x$ is a zero of  $ X^n+1+(-1)^n(X+1)^n$ then $|x|=1$ or $|x+1|=1$ or $|x+1|=|x|$.

My initial thought was to study the cases $n=2,3,4$ (that confirm indeed the result) in order to establish a general approach, but I didn't succeed to do this.

Answer (score 6):

The set of roots of this polynomial has several symmetries:

- It is symmetric in the line $\operatorname{Im}(z) = 0$.
- It is symmetric in the line $\operatorname{Re}(z) = -\tfrac{1}{2}$.
- It is symmetric under $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ ($z \neq 0$).

Note that the last symmetry maps the line $\operatorname{Re}(z) = -\tfrac{1}{2}$ to $\{z \mid |z+1|=1\}$ and vice versa.

If $n$ is odd then $\{-1,0\}$ are roots.  Let $\zeta$ be a primitive third root of unity.  Then $\zeta + 1$ is a primitive sixth root of unity.  If $3 \nmid n$ then $\zeta^{\pm 1}$ are roots and if $n \equiv 1, 4$ ($\bmod$ $6$) then $\zeta^{\pm 1}$ are double roots.  (One can check this by considering the derivative at $\zeta^{\pm 1}$.)

If we can show that the polynomial has sufficiently many zeroes on the unit circle then its symmetries may suffice to locate *all* zeroes, which will then automatically satisfy the required conditions.

Substitute $X \leftarrow e^{2it}$ to get

$$\begin{eqnarray}
e^{2i n t} + 1 + (-1)^n(e^{2it} + 1)^n &=& e^{2int} + 1 + (-1)^ne^{int}(2\cos(t))^n \\
&=& e^{int}\left(2\cos(nt) + 2^n(-\cos(t))^n \right) 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and therefore $e^{2it}$ is a zero precisely if $$ \cos(nt) + 2^{n-1}(-\cos(t))^n = 0.$$

If $t \in [\tfrac{\pi}{3}, \tfrac{\pi}{2}]$ then $|2^{n-1}\cos(t)^n| \leq \tfrac{1}{2}$ while $\cos(n t)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$.  Therefore there must be a root between any two points where $\cos(nt)$ goes from $-1$ to $1$ or vice versa.  Now $\cos(n t)= \pm 1$ precisely if $nt=m \pi$ for some integer $m$.  By symmetry, each root in the *open* interval accounts for six roots of the polynomial.  Let's check what happens by considering six different cases $n$ $\bmod$ $6$.

$n = 6k$: $\cos(n t) = \pm 1$ when $2k \leq m \leq 3k$ so $k+1$ times and therefore at least $k$ roots on the open interval. All $6k$ roots are accounted for.

$n=6k+1$. At least double roots at $\zeta^{\pm 1}$ and simple roots at $\{-1,0\}$. Now $\cos(n t) = \pm 1$ when $2k + 1 \leq m \leq 3k$ so $k$ times accounting for at least $k-1$ roots.  So all $6k$ roots are accounted for.

$n=6k+2$. At least simple roots at $\zeta^{\pm 1}$. Now $\cos(n t) = \pm 1$ when $2k + 1 \leq m \leq 3k + 1$ so $k + 1$ times accounting for at least $k$ roots.    So all $6k + 2$ roots are accounted for.

$n=6k+3$. At least simple roots at $\{-1,0\}$.  Now $\cos(n t) = \pm 1$ when $2k + 1 \leq m \leq 3k + 1$ so $k + 1$ times accounting for at least $k$ roots.    So all $6k + 2$ roots are accounted for.

$n=6k+4$. At least double roots at $\zeta^{\pm 1}$.  Now $\cos(n t) = \pm 1$ when $2k + 2 \leq m \leq 3k + 2$ so $k + 1$ times accounting for at least $k$ roots.    So all $6k + 4$ roots are accounted for.

$n=6k+5$. At least simple roots at $\zeta^{\pm 1}$ and $\{-1,0\}$.  Now $\cos(n t) = \pm 1$ when $2k + 2 \leq m \leq 3k + 2$ so $k + 1$ times accounting for at least $k$ roots.  So all $6k + 4$ roots are accounted for.

So in all cases we conclude that the roots satisfy the required conditions.

Comment: Excellent! I got as far as $n\mod 6$ effect on the symmetries, but never considered using good old real analysis on the unit circle. Although the nearly-equal spacing of zeros there should have given me a clue to switch to trigonometric functions.

Answer (score -1):

**The following doesn't really help:**

This *seems* like a homework problem, so I'm leaving the details to you. But the key idea is to use the argument principle. For example, <strike>we can show that there are no roots with |z|<1</strike> examine what occurs when $|z|<1$ and either $|z+1|<1$ or $|z+1|>1$ by considering $\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ for any closed contour contained inside <strike>the unit circle</strike> one of these domains (where $f(z)$ is your polynomial, after factoring out the trivial zeros). Then the integrand is a holomorphic function on this domain (prove it), so the integral evaluates to zero and thus there are no zeros in the interior of the unit circle.

In a similar way, you can extend to consider the domain on which $|z|>1$ and $|z| > |z+1|$, as well as the domain on which $|z| > 1$ and $|z| < |z+1|$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it does not. For one thing, there are roots in $|z|<1$, as you could see from the [image I posted](http://i.imgur.com/kTgbrTJ.png).

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake with the details, but actually the technique still works. It just means you need to partition into more domains (i.e., more casework when $|z|<1$). If you actually compute the integrand I was talking about, this will become clearer.

Comment: To rephrase, let $S$ denote the points in the complex plane that satisfy at least one of your constraints. Then we must show that on each connected component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$, the integrand is holomorphic. This will show that there are no zeros in $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$, so all zeros must lie in $S$, proving your statement.

Comment: To show there are no roots of $f$ in some region, you propose to use the fact that $f'/f$ is holomorphic, remarking "prove it". But to show that $f'/f$ is holomorphic in some domain, one has to know that $f$ does not turn into zero there. This is not helpful at all.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. This doesn't help unless it happens that $\log f$ is easier to handle than $f$, which is not the case here.